# Make background cover all screen sizes

Tags: android, css, background

I have a code which makes a background picture cover the whole screen, not just the content. It works fine with a computer and an iPhone but with an android the picture doesn't stretch length wise to cover the whole screen vertically. The code is as follows.

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-image:url(background.png);
    border:none;
    background-size:100%;
    -webkit-background-size:100%;
    -moz-background-size:100%;
    -o-background-size:100%;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

The image is 5x500 pixels. If you have a better solution to cover a page with a background image then let me know.

Comment: Why does your non-prefixed background-size include 6%?

Comment: @mattcurtis What do you mean with non-prefixed? I use the 6% because otherwise it doesn't cover the whole screen vertically.

Comment: -webkit-, -o-, etc, are called vendor prefixes, meaning they are meant  to target different browsers/engines. I am referring to the background-size property that does not have a vendor prefix.

Comment: I don't know why I had it there, with trying so many different things i guess i got messed up!

Comment: It could be a part of the problem. Have you tried your corrected code?

Comment: Yes I have tried it but it still doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Can't you just use background-repeat: repeat;? Do you want it to stretch or something? If you're using a LARGE image you want stretched over the screen, then use width: 100%; height: auto;

Comment: @JustinMcCraw Yes, I want the image stretched vertically and horizontally. Using background-repeat:repeat; just makes it repeat, not stretch. Using the width and height doesn't either work.

Comment: It might be more feasible, simple and cross-browser have an element called <img id="bg" /> and style that. You can use fixed positioning on it, and it should do what you want. Of course, you'll have to use z-index and ensure that your content is above that background.

Comment: Another note: have you just played around with background-size on android?

Comment: @mattcurtis I have tried it on desktop and IPhone as well.

Comment: But the only issue is on Android, correct?

Comment: @mattcurtis Yes, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

Background size can ggive problems sometimes. Try adding a `min-height` to `html`

Try Adding

```
min-height: 100%;
```

to the body

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your properties like this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
```

`backround-size` can be finicky.

Comment: I have barely tried that and it still doesn't work. Android maybe doesn't understand background-size? Is there another solution to stretch an image vertically and repeat horizontally?

Comment: There's the method I suggested in the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at background-size:contain?  Personally, I am a fan of background-size:cover, which may help as well.

I came across this post because I was looking at an Android background size issue.  If it doesn't help the OP, at least hopefully, it will help someone else.

The android issue is related I experienced was Android not liking the shorthand for background and having a background-position and a background-size.  Separating, like it looks like you have, solved the issue.